I want to achive this nested list UI in flutter
How could we achive this UI in flutter?
The top row buttons hide when scroll up and visible when scroll down and the listview is wrap in a card widget.
https://youtube.com/shorts/6e3q47AMXoU?si=428FC8uTk3TSJcTt

You can achieve this behavior using CustomScrollView and SliverAppBar. Use the top one as pinned as a toolbar and for the Row Buttons, you can use SliverAppBar without pinning.
Here is the example code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
              title: const Text(
                "Example Scrolling",
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SliverAppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
              toolbarHeight: 100,
              flexibleSpace: Center(
                  child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Demo"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Demo"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Demo"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Card(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 16,
                  vertical: 16,
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 50,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text("List Item - ${index + 1}"),
                      subtitle: const Text("Description here"),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thanks for the answer, but I want the whole card to visible on the screen. In your code the bottom of the card is only visible when scroll down.

You can archive a header that hides when the user scrolls down and shows when they scroll up by using a combination of the SliverAppBar and CustomScrollView
Here's a basic example :
Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              const SliverAppBar(
                floating: true,
                snap: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                title: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.history_rounded,color: Colors.white,size: 30,),
                    Icon(Icons.wallet,color: Colors.white,size: 30),
                    Icon(Icons.inventory_outlined,color: Colors.white,size: 30),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('Your Data $index'),
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    )


The list should be in a card

You can use sliver appBar for creating this types of ui in flutter.
Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),

        /// floating property used to hide and unhide while screen is scrolling.
        floating: true,
        forceElevated: true,
        primary: true,
        centerTitle: true,

        /// stretch property used to add streched effect while screen is scrolling.
        stretch: true,
        bottom: const CommonAppBar(
          leading: SizedBox.shrink(),
          title: Text("Goa"),
        ),

        /// if you need to add second app bar
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        pinned: true, // if you need to pinned appbar while scrolling time

        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        expandedHeight: 250.0,
        flexibleSpace: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
          ),
          child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
            centerTitle: false,
            title: const Text(
              'Goa',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            background: Image.network(
              'https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/40/51/56/360_F_140515612_0MMpqpsIvs6xno5YXmPVy9FUmZ4uLnFB.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      //3
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (_, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  width: 100,
                  child: const Placeholder()),
              title: Text('Place ${index + 1}'),
            );
          },
          addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
          addRepaintBoundaries: true,
          childCount: 20,
          addSemanticIndexes: true,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);


But the list must be in a card

After trying lot's of things i found this working as required, Thanks everyone for helping.
NestedScrollView(
                floatHeaderSlivers: true,
                headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                  return [
                    const SliverAppBar(
                      floating: true,
                      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(),
                      expandedHeight: 100,
                    ),
                  ];
                },
                body: Card.outlined(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return const ListTile(
                        title: Text("data"),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),

